# Self hosted domain does not respond from local network

Tags: networking, domain, port-forwarding

I have a self hosted website with domain example.com

I have a static public IP on my router and I port forward (80 and 443) from the router to my server, passing through a nginx reverse proxy.

If I access my web page https://example.com from the internet, I can see the web page with no problem. But if I try to access it from my local network it responds with "This site can’t be reached".

I have read a bit on loopback Nat as it could be a possible problem. but if I do a ping from a local computer to example.com, the ping answers back with the correct public IP and correct ping response. So, it it's not a loopback problem and it's not a DNS problem as during the ping the public IP gets resolved correctly.

The local server IP is 192.168.0.50, and I can access it from my local network using the local IP.

Furthermore I've had this same setup working for over 2 years. This local network access problem started 2 weeks ago. Before that it worked just fine.

What else could I check? Any pointers?

Thanks

Comment: Welcome, home and enduser questions are off topic. You need to implement on split-dns imho.

Comment: What happens when you create an entry in your host file for the domain and the ip. And what do you get when you do `curl -I example.com` from internal. And a tcpdump

Comment: Superuser.com. Learn to set up your NAT properly. This place is for professionals following best practices. Also a hint: do not expose your server like that, learn of cloudlare and their publication zero trust tunnels.

Comment: Split-brain DNS is a thing.

Comment: Does the domain still work from outside? Is your external IP address still the same as before? Does your router's status page agree on what IP address it is?

Comment: @Turdie  `curl` command just hangs with no response... Then: `curl: (28) Failed to connect to qsoftsv.com port 80 after 75171 ms: Couldn't connect to server.`  `ping` does a good response and `traceroute` also answeres with the public IP

Comment: @u1686_grawity Yes the domain workd for the outside. And the IP has not changed. My router gets the IP from the ISP's DHCP and the IP has not changed.

Comment: Can you use tcpdump to verify that it's not actually a NAT loopback problem? (Pinging the address doesn't verify that, since you're not NATing ping anywhere, you're just pinging the router itself.)